# Class with DataAnnotation [Table("Tablename")] inherit by another class with variable get set not working?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, data-annotations

Working with a class:

DBContext:

```
public SDBContext() : base("name=SPDBContext")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
        public DbSet<Table1> table_1 { get; set; }
```

A Class with Annotation:

```
[Table("table_1")]
   public abstract class Table1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dt { get; set; }

    }
```

A normal Class to inherit the class above:

```
public class InheritTable1 : Table1
    {
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public static DataTable GetTable1()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SDBContext sdb = new SDBContext();
                var getData = sdb.table_1.ToList();
                dt.Merge(CollecTables.ToDataTable(getData));
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                throw er;
            }
        }
    }
```

Implementation:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = InheritTable1.GetTable1();
```

If i remove this section of code:

```
public String Address { get; set; }
```

It is working well.

But if i run that code with `public String Address { get; set; }`

It returns an error:

> Message = "Unknown column 'Extent1.Address' in 'field list'"

I knew this `Extent1` means reading from `Table1 Class`. why it is treated as `Table1` instead of `InheritTable1`.

All that i knew is:
A class that inherit an Abstract Class can Add a method anytime we wanted but my question is:

why it can't be done with it's own variable (with this class `InheritTable1`)?

Comment: What is your dbcontext, DbSet/IDebSet signature or modelbuilder code and what is the table structure in the db of this table?, my suspicions are that database doesn't have the inherited table at all.. Please update your question with this relevant information

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral updated the question above.

Comment: Take a look at EF inheritance strategies. What you have currently is [Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) which uses single table to store the data for all derived entities.